# Msg 7391 The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider for linked server was unable to begin a distributed transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server, distributed-transactions, msdtc

There is 3 Sql Server. Example Server A, Server B and Server C.

-DTC is running in all the machine.

-Local DTC Properties in all three machine:

```
      -Network DTC Access

      -Allow Inbound

      -Allow Outboud

      -No Authentication Required  

      -Enable XA Transaction

      -Enable SNA LU 6.2 Transaction

      -Account: NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService
```

RPC and RPC OUT is true for link server

Server A: Windows 8, Server B: Windows 7 and Server C: Windows 7

Firewall is off in all three servers

Servers are not in Domain.

Added "set xact_abort on" in the query.

Now, From server A Distributed transaction work fine in both machine.

```
    From server B Distributed transaction work in Server A only.

    From server c Distributed transaction work in Server A only.
```

Problem: Distributed Transaction does not work between server B and C.

Answer (score 0):

May be you have problem with configuration of your firewalls on A\B\C servers. You can try to temporally disable firewalls to check this.  See following [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753510(v=ws.10).aspx) for more details about "Enable Network DTC Access".

Comment: Firewall is off in all three servers.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was due to same unique identity in MSDTC of server B and server C.  This means that the two MS DTC will not be able to communicate with each other. This problem typically occurs if one of the systems were cloned using unsupported cloning tools. MS DTC requires that the systems be cloned using supported cloning tools such as SYSPREP. Running 'msdtc -uninstall' and then 'msdtc -install' from the command prompt will fix the problem. Note: Running 'msdtc -uninstall' will result in the system losing all MS DTC configuration information. Note: In Windows 2008 use Administrator command prompt, service must be stopped and you must reboot the server.

http://www.sqlwebpedia.com/content/msdtc-troubleshooting